# nuxt: pass data from server plugin to client

Tags: nuxt.js

I have a nuxt behind an auth proxy. A request will get to nuxt (only if) it is authorized, in which case the `X-auth-username` (and other) headers will be set.

I have found that, using a server plugin, I can read this info on the request. However, the data is not send from the server to the client. How do I get the server to send information headers (in particular the user name) to the client?

My plugin so far:

```js
import { Plugin } from '@nuxt/types'
import { IncomingHttpHeaders } from 'http'

declare module '@nuxt/types' {
  interface NuxtAppOptions {
    $headers: IncomingHttpHeaders
  }
}

const getAuth: Plugin = (context, inject) => {
  const headers = context.req.headers
  inject('headers', headers)
}

export default getAuth
```

*NOTE* I am using the `nuxt-composition-api`, and not vuex.

Comment: you can use a server middleware to achieve this.
https://nuxtjs.org/api/configuration-servermiddleware/

Comment: @BillSomen That gives me access to the request, but how/where to I put the info to pass to the client? (Already in the server plugin I have access to the request -- so that isn't the problem per se.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [beforeNuxtRender](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/internals-glossary/context/#beforenuxtrender) nuxt hook to set properties on server which will be serialized in html and retrievable on client:

```
// in nuxt plugin
if (process.server) {
    // set property on server
    context.beforeNuxtRender(({ nuxtState }) => {
      nuxtState.headerValue = 'test';
    });
} else {
    // retrieve it on client
    let valueOnClient = context.nuxtState?.headerValue;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[Injected `header`](https://nuxtjs.org/guide/plugins#inject-in-root-amp-context) should be available as `$headers` in templates or lifecycle methods of components as `this.$headers`.

Comment: When I inject on the server, I see it in the server. The task is to get it to the client after reading it from the request on the server. Right now I'm putting it in a cookie, which seems to work, but I would prefer to get it into the webpack bundle.